# sum by keys in array by summing up relavent keys

Tags: javascript

I have array as below

```
[
["game1",25],
["game2",25],
["game3",40],
["game1",45],
["game2",45],
]
```

I would like to have output as below:

```
[
["game1",70]
["game2",70]
["game3",40]
]
```

I have tried using array.reduce but it is not working, any help ?
my part

```
   aboveArray.reduce((acc,curr)=>{
       acc[curr[0]] ? acc[curr[0] += acc[curr[1]] : acc[curr[0]]=acc[curr[1]]
    return acc;
    },[])
```

Comment: reduce and object.entries

Comment: SHOW what you tried, maybe it is a typo.... maybe you were 90% of the way there. We do not know since we can't see what you tried.

Comment: If we don't know what you tried, we can't help you figure out where the problem was. If we just post a solution,  it may not help you figure out what the problem was

Comment: I added my code, please see and revert

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the items into an accumulated value object "map" and then convert the resulting object into an entry list.

```js
const data = [
  [ "game1", 25 ],
  [ "game2", 25 ],
  [ "game3", 40 ],
  [ "game1", 45 ],
  [ "game2", 45 ]
];

const reduced = Object.entries(data.reduce((acc, [key, value]) =>
  ({ ...acc, [key]: (acc[key] ?? 0) + value }), {}));

console.log(JSON.stringify(reduced));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code is you are still trying to work with an array. It can be done, just not very efficient. You want to look into using an Object.

Using Object.entries and reduce you can get the format you want.

```js
var data = [
  ["game1", 25],
  ["game2", 25],
  ["game3", 40],
  ["game1", 45],
  ["game2", 45],
];

var result = Object.entries(data.reduce((acc, game) => {
  acc[game[0]] = (acc[game[0]] || 0) + game[1];
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sum the value with `array#reduce` then reform with `Object.entries` . And `??` is called [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

```js
const arr = [ ["game1",25], ["game2",25], ["game3",40], ["game1",45], ["game2",45], ];

const res = Object.entries(
                arr.reduce((acc, curr) =>
                   (acc[curr[0]] = (acc[curr[0]] ?? 0) + curr[1],acc) 
                 ,{})
              );

console.log(res)
```